# Increase label7.text by 1 everytime the user makes a wrong guess

Tags: c#

Everytime the user makes a wrong guess I want the label7.text to display that number. the way i have it it just stays at 1 and doesnt increment the next wrong guess.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)


    {
        int correct=0;
        int incorrect=0;
        RandomNumber(0,99);
        button2.Enabled = true ;
        button1.Enabled = false;
        label3.Visible = true;
        if (textBox1.Text == label1.Text)
        {
            label3.Text = (string.Format("Winner"));
            label6.Text = (++correct).ToString();
        }

        else if (textBox1.Text != label1.Text)
        {
            label7.Text = (++incorrect).ToString(); 
            label3.Text = (string.Format("Sorry - You Lose, The number is {0}", label1.Text));
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the variables `correct` and `incorrect` from your button click's scope, and make them class-level variables instead.  In your code, every time a user clicks the button, these variables are re-initialized to 0.

Like this:

```
private int correct = 0;
private int incorrect = 0;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)


    {
        RandomNumber(0,99);
        button2.Enabled = true ;
        button1.Enabled = false;
        label3.Visible = true;
        if (textBox1.Text == label1.Text)
        {
            label3.Text = (string.Format("Winner"));
            label6.Text = (++correct).ToString();
        }

        else if (textBox1.Text != label1.Text)
        {
            label7.Text = (++incorrect).ToString(); 
            label3.Text = (string.Format("Sorry - You Lose, The number is {0}", label1.Text));
        }


    }
```